# Mapbox - Issue with elements disappearing at certain zoom level

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

First time posting here.

I am using Mapbox to create styles for maps.  I have set Buildings layer to have a constant color and opacity across all zoom levels but the buildings still disappear when I zoom out past 15.  What am I missing?

[image: 1]

I want the buildings to remain visible at all zoom levels.  Is there a global setting that I'm missing somewhere?